# Applying overflow:hidden to .mat-tab-body-content

Tags: angular6

Applying overflow:hidden to .mat-tab-body-content.
I have provided overflow-x:hidden in css but also it is not getting

Answer (score 1):

If you mean hiding Overflow in css, the answer is :

```
 .mat-tab-body-content {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Or:

```
 .mat-tab-body-content {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: .mat-tab-body-content{
    overflow-x:hidden !important;
  }

Comment: I have created this code on css file but the its not reflecting.

Comment: I want the mat-tab-body to have overflow hidden as its default value is overflow:auto

Comment: .mat-tab-body-content {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto; } THIS IS THE DEFAULT VALUE

Answer (score 1):

If you what to apply the style in the component css then you have use

```
::ng-deep .mat-tab-body-content {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

with **::ng-deep**. In this way the style is applied only in the component where scss belongs. Otherwise you have to change the global style file.